# Independence of an event with null probability with another event.

Tags: probability-theory

Suppose we have an event $A$ with $P(A) = 0$, and let $B$ be any other event. Prove that $A$ and $B$ are independent.

It seems rather obvious that since $P(A \cap B) = P(A)P(B)$ if they're independent, and $P(A)P(B) = 0$, so $A$ and $B$ will be independent regardless since $A \cap B$ must have Lebesgue measure 0. However, I'm not satisfied with this "proof". Is it possible that it's not always true?

Comment: What do you find unsatisfactory about it? I find it unsatisfactory from the following point-of-view: If A and B are independent, I excpect P(B|A) = P(B). However, this only makes sense when P(A) is not 0.

Comment: Example: Suppose X is uniformly distributed on [0,1]. Let A be the event X = 0.6 and let B be the event X > 0.5 Then P(B) = 0.5 and P(B|A) = 1, event though P(A) = 0.

Comment: Conditioning on an event of measure zero is not defined (the information you get from such an event is not realistic). Though independence is quite intuitive, because since such an event will never occur "nothing" can depend from it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is always true. If $\Pr(A)=0$, then $\Pr(A\cap B)=0$. So $\Pr(A\cap B)=\Pr(A)\Pr(B)$. It is hardly ever *Lebesgue* measure, it is whatever probability measure in involved.

Answer (score 1):

$A\cap B \subseteq A$ and $\rm P$ is non-negative and monotone thus $\rm P(A\cap B)=0$, as $\rm P(A\cap B) \leq \rm P(A) =0$. So $\rm P(A\cap B) =\rm P(A)\rm P(B)$. This seems a fair enough proof.

Comment: In what sense is $\textrm P$ monotone? I don't think monotonicity is required.

Comment: Using the "subset" property using a good way for this simple proof.

Comment: monotone in usual sense, as $P$ is defined on sets, ie,   $A\subseteq B$ implies $P(A)\leq P(B)$